# Is this a way of emphasizing "or" to pronounce it as "o ra"?

Tags: pronunciation

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/1bSkQ93jEHM?t=331) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> we can also use *get to* with *him* or *her* **or me** or *you* after.

where there is a clear "ra" in "or me"

## question

Is this a way of emphasizing "or" to pronounce it as "o ra"? or that is just his personal style?

Comment: It's "or, *ah*,me." The "ah" is just a hesitation to give the speaker time to think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "him or her or, er, me".  Where "er" is a [filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)).  In transcribed speech you may also also see this transcribed as "err", "uh", "uhh", etc.

There's nothing particularly meaningful about where he inserts it after the "or" -- he could equally have said "him or her, er, or me" depending on where his brain/mouth happened to pause at that moment.